# In my django admin change_list, there are names with diacritics. How to order them properly?

Tags: python, django, diacritics

I'm using it with **Python 3.6.5**. In my **Django 2.1** app, I have a model object like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

with some names presenting diacritics. In my `admin.py`, I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['name']

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

So, this is the default order I got when accessing my `change_list` admin view:

```
Joseph
Josué
José
Éderson
```

but I need them to show up in this order:

```
Éderson
Joseph
José
Josué
```

Also, I have a sort key to do this trick when I have a list:

```
import locale

def sort_key_BR():
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "pt_BR.UTF-8")
    return locale.strxfrm

names = ['Joseph', 'Josué', 'José', 'Éderson']
names.sort(key=sort_key_BR())
for n in names:
    print(n) # Éderson Joseph José Josué
```

Worth to mention, in my project's `settings.py`, I already have:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-BR'
```

What is the proper way to inform a sort key rather than the default to `ordering` in Django models? Rather what is a proper way of doing this?

Comment: Items are sorted in the database. This sounds like an issue with your database collation.

Comment: Even if it is an issue with my database, which I don't think it is the case, `ordering` is sorting my data (ascending in this example) with respect to the string in the `name` field after the query. Isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The admin view is asking your db to return the items in sorted order, there's no sorting happening in Python.

Comment: Ok, I was not aware of that. I'll try to investigate it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use an other filed with autofill and put away "é" and other stuff :

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url = self.name.replace("é", "e").lower()
        super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['url']

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```